# Get day text function returned undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure where is the logic flaw with my function below, I'm trying to get the day value in string.

```
function getDayText(date){
        var weekday = new Array(7);

        weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";

        return weekday[date];
}

console.log(getDayText(2016-1-1)) // undefined
```

Comment: Problem is your parameter `2016-1-1` is not a valid date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your parameter `2016-1-1` is not a valid date.

```js
//no need to create array for each call
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

var day = function(str) {
  var tmp = new Date(str); //create date
  return days[tmp.getDay()];
};

alert(day('2016-1-1')); //<-- note, its string
```

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
console.log(getDayText(2016-1-1));
```

is the same as:

```
console.log(getDayText(2014));
```

but your `weekday` array only has 7 elements, not 2014. So it's normal that you get `undefined` when you attempt to access the 2014th element of this array. Make sure that you specify only valid indexes (In your case that would be from 0 to 6). For example:

```
console.log(getDayText(3));
```

Comment: so you have a good solution? I want to pass 2016-1-1 as my date.

Comment: ok, then you could use the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the day of the week to get the intended result.

`console.log(getDayText(new Date("2016-1-1").getDay()));`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Pass your date as a (valid) string to it's constructor, and use [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method to get the day of week.

```js
function getDayText(date){
 var weekday = new Array(7);

 weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
 weekday[1] = "Monday";
 weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
 weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
 weekday[4] = "Thursday";
 weekday[5] = "Friday";
 weekday[6] = "Saturday";

 return weekday[new Date(date).getDay()];
}

document.write('<pre>' + getDayText("2016-01-01") + '</pre>');
```

I'd prefer you pass a Date object to your method rather than a string, so to tidy it up:

```js
function getDayText(date) {
  var days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ];
  return days[date.getDay()];
}

document.write('<pre>' + getDayText(new Date("2016-01-01")) + '</pre>');
```